# C++_win32: pthread_self() == pthread_t leading to error

Tags: c++, windows, pthreads

I'm trying to port linux working application to windows (using `windows.h` and POSIX `pthread_win32`)

So, I have a field of clients defined:

```
struct ClientIdentifier {
  pthread_t thread;
  int id_client;
  ...
};

vector<ClientIdentifier> clients;
```

and I'm trying to find thread of this client in field of clients (returning index of field)

```
int Server::getClientIndex() {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < clients.size(); ++i) {
    if (pthread_self() == clients.at(i).thread) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

But this:

```
pthread_self() == clients.at(i).thread
```

results to:

```
34 D:\WORKSPACE\C++\DS\gs\server.cpp no match for 'operator==' in 'pthread_self() == (((std::vector<ClientIdentifier, std::allocator<ClientIdentifier> >*)((Server*)this)) + 8u)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::at [with _Tp = ClientIdentifier, _Alloc = std::allocator<ClientIdentifier>](i)->ClientIdentifier::thread' 

note C:\programy\DevCpp\include\objbase.h:80 candidates are: BOOL operator==(const GUID&, const GUID&)
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pthread_equal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_equal.html) to compare `pthread_t` values.